# Bring process to foreground in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I want to bring a running process to front on a button click event.

On button click I am able to run application using below code:

```
dynamic shell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.Run("cmd.exe", 1, true);
```

But is there any way by which I can bring already running cmd(any applicaion) to foreground in Silverlight 5. I am using silverlight out of browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for Bring window to front as discussed here [Bring another processes Window to foreground when it has ShowInTaskbar = false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636721/bring-another-processes-window-to-foreground-when-it-has-showintaskbar-false)

Comment: This works fine if I know the application title, but if I don't know title and I know only process name(say notepad.exe) how can I bring that application to front by it's process name?