# Activating Form By Title Throws System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, process, combobox, bringtofront

so I have a form with a `ComboBox` that I populate with a list of open processes (In this case, I limit it to processes with titles that have 13 characters.) When I select an `Item` in the `ComboBox` I want to find that `Form` by Title and `BringToFront` However when I do so, it throws a `System.NullReferenceException`.

Here's the code I use to populate the box.

```
using HWND = IntPtr;
public static class OpenWindowGetter
{
    /// <summary>Returns a dictionary that contains the handle and title of all the open windows.</summary>
    /// <returns>A dictionary that contains the handle and title of all the open windows.</returns>
    public static IDictionary<HWND, string> GetOpenWindows()
    {
        HWND shellWindow = GetShellWindow();
        Dictionary<HWND, string> windows = new Dictionary<HWND, string>();

        EnumWindows(delegate (HWND hWnd, int lParam)
        {
            if (hWnd == shellWindow) return true;
            if (!IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) return true;

            int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
            if (length == 0) return true;

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(length);
            GetWindowText(hWnd, builder, length + 1);

            windows[hWnd] = builder.ToString();
            return true;

        }, 0);

        return windows;
    }

    private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, int lParam);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumFunc, int lParam);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    private static extern int GetWindowText(HWND hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(HWND hWnd);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(HWND hWnd);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();
}

public void populateIncidents()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<IntPtr, string> window in OpenWindowGetter.GetOpenWindows())
        {
            IntPtr handle = window.Key;
            string title = window.Value;
            if (title.Length == 13)
            {
                chooseIncidentBox.Items.Add(title);
            }
        }
    }
```

And here's the code I'm using to try to show the Form.

```
private void chooseIncidentBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sSelectedIncident = chooseIncidentBox.Text;
        Application.OpenForms[sSelectedIncident].BringToFront(); //Exception thrown here.
    }
```

I'm not quite sure why it's throwing the exception, I know the Form exists as it wouldn't populate the `ComboBox` otherwise. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: EnumWindows can enumerate all windows in "Windows", but Application.OpenForms can retrieve windows only in "windows in your process". Definitely, OpenForms[...] may return null in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have gives all the active windows. Now, `Application.OpenForms` works only on the forms which are opened in your application. For example, if you have `ParentForm` and `ChildForm`in your application and both are open, `OpenForms` collection will contain these two.

What you are looking for is to bring any process window in front. You can make use of `SetForegroundWindow` in `User32.dll` to do so. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636721/bring-another-processes-window-to-foreground-when-it-has-showintaskbar-false) SO question looks fairly similar to what you need. Take a look at the accepted solution.