# C# console application bring process to foreground

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, console-application

With the following C# console application code, I am able to run the process in background using Jenkins. But now I want to see this process in foreground. What wrong I am doing here ?

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr handle);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr handle, int nCmdShow);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr handle);

private void startT32app()
{
    IntPtr handle;
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("T32 launching");
        string path = @"C:\T32\bin\windows64\t32mppc.exe";
        string args = @"C:\T32\config.t32";
        ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path, args);
        procInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        procInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        procInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

        Process procRun = Process.Start(procInfo);
        handle = procRun.MainWindowHandle;
        SetForegroundWindow(handle);
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to launch T32");
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    Program Beginapps = new Program();
    Beginapps.startT32app();        
}
```

Comment: You could be trying to bring it to the foreground before it has displayed its main window. Perhaps calling [`WaitForInputIdle()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) first might help. Also be aware of the rules governing whether a process is allowed to make another window the foreground, documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @MatthewWatson - I doubt a console application can ever qualify under those rules.

Comment: I am not going to click on the consol window. So wait for consol window is somewhat not okay unless I don't need to click on the consol window and still can finish the C# program to exit. But when I am running the process, I should be able to see it in foreground.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It can - a console application can launch a Windows app and make it the foreground (as long as the console app is the foreground process - which it will be if, for example, the user just clicked a shortcut to launch it or clicked the EXE in Windows Explorer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An option to achieve your task is to send shift + tab to the window to set it in front of everything (i tried in another application different ways, but only this worked for me):

```
// is used to set window in front
[DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern void SwitchToThisWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool fAltTab);

public void startT32app()
{
    IntPtr handle;
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("T32 launching");
        string path = @"C:\T32\bin\windows64\t32mppc.exe";
        string args = @"C:\T32\config.t32";
        ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path, args);
        procInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        procInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        procInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

        Process procRun = Process.Start(procInfo);
        handle = procRun.MainWindowHandle;
        SwitchToThisWindow(handle, true);
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to launch T32");
    }
}
```